# Several groups of features: at most one of each group selected simultaneously

Tags: openlayers-3

Let's say I have two groups of features with different properties on a single map: features A and features B. I'm setting up a single interaction for both feature types because [there can be only one](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/1988).

If I select one A feature, then one B feature, the A feature is removed from the featureCollection. How can I have them both selected at the same time ? I also want to have at most one feature of each type selected.

Example use case:

```
Click on A1 --> add A1
Click on A2 --> remove A1 and add A2
Click on B1 --> add B1
Click elsewhere on map -->remove A2 and B1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest instead of the select interaction, just creating your own `featureOverlay` and adding the features as needed.

```
var overlay = new ol.featureOverlay({
  style: selectedStyle
});

map.on('click', function (event) {
  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, function (f) { return f;});
  // handle the add/remove logic here
  if (feature.get('group') === 'A') {
    overlay.addFeature(feature);
  } 
  // etc...
});
```

Comment: I never managed to get a styleFunction to work within a featureOverlay (nothing ever happened) so I ended up rewriting my own selection manager based on the the singleclick event...kinda like how you suggest except I use a selectedFeatures collection instead of the overlay and I set styles manually when features are added/removed. Thanks anyway